# How to find longest common substring with less memory usage?

Tags: algorithm

I need to find longest common substring with greatest **(length of substring * count)**.

For example, when I have string:

```
hi, hello world ... hello world ... hi, hello world
```

The answer is `hello world`, because **(11 * 3) > (15 * 2)**.

I have found a relevant discussion in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004123/how-to-find-longest-common-substring-using-trees), but it is not practical to use in my case, because of its high memory usage.

Is there any better way how to do that?

Comment: are these suitable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158025/longest-common-substring-in-two-sequences-of-strings

Comment: In the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) there is a pseudocode solution using dynamic programming.

Comment: A little. He is looking for longest substring. I'm looking for substring that takes most of space in the string (gratest length of substring * count)

Comment: "it is not practical to use this because it's high memory use". I disagree. you will insert each string in the trie, which will have a number of characters smaller than the sum of characters of each string. And you can divide the problems if there are too many strings to fit in memory

Comment: google "generalized suffix tree"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the assumption than an existing approach on SO has "high memory usage" is neither explained nor proven

Comment: why is the answer not " hello world"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in perl.  Probably it is not memory efficient but it works with the test string shown

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $s="hi, hello world ... hello world ... hi, hello world";
my %h=();

#find the repeated strings, all of them
for (0..length($s) ) { 
    my $x=substr($s,$_); 
    for my  $m ($x=~/(.*).*\1/) { $h{$m}++} ; }

#find the count of each strings repeats
for my $f (keys %h) { $h{$f} = () = $s=~/\Q$f/g; }

#sort the length*count to find the best
my @ord=sort { length($b)*$h{$b} <=> length($a)*$h{$a} } keys %h;

#this one is the best
print $ord[0];
```